# Java Stream divide integer list to 3 parts and sum of each parts

Tags: java, java-8

I need to divide  Integer list in to equal parts and print sum of the each array

ex  [4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]

divide on to [4,2,3] , [4,1.1], [1,2,1] and sum of each final out put 964

need to do with java 8 stream api

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

Integer[] array = {4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1};


Arrays.asList(array).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter .getAndIncrement() / 3)).forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k + " " + v));
```

it prints

```
{0=[4, 2, 3], 1=[4, 1, 1], 2=[1, 2, 1]}
```

I need to print sum of each parts 
964

Thanks

Comment: This is just a list of requirements. It's not a question. We're not a free code-writing service, sorry.

Comment: How about if the size if a prime number ? Like 7, how do you divide it ? in sublist of 1 ?

Comment: sorry michael I know how to do that from java 7 but I need to do that from java 8               Integer[] array = {4, 2, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0};
  
Arrays.asList(array).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter2.getAndIncrement() / 3)).forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k + " " + v));

Comment: Share your java 7 code, because there will often multiples possibilities to have "equal part". For a 20 length : 2x10, 4x5, 5x4, 10x2 ?

Comment: Your code is splitting the array into parts of length three instead of three parts. It just happens to be the same when the source array has exactly nine elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stop the problem at the point you have the `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` : `{0=[4, 2, 3], 1=[4, 1, 1], 2=[1, 2, 1]}`

You need to

- iterate over the differents `Lists`
- sum their elements
- print them (or collect them to build an `int`)

```
Arrays.asList(array).stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter .getAndIncrement() / 3))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .mapToInt(val-> val.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum())
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

[***`Workable Demo : print`***](https://ideone.com/zEjPx0)

To get a `String` of that

```
String res = Arrays.asList(array).stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter .getAndIncrement() / 3))
        .values().stream()
        .map(val-> val.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum())
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println(res);
```

[***`Workable Demo : collect as String`***](https://ideone.com/YvSeiU)

---

A shorter way, but not more readable, can be :

- iterate over `ints`, separated by `3` in your case : 0, 3, 6, 9, ...
- map each one  to the sum of the values of the array from `index` to `index+3`

```
IntStream.iterate(0,i->i+size)
    .limit(array.length/size)
    .map(i -> Arrays.stream(array).skip(i).limit(size).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum())
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: Thanks azaro thats what i want

Comment: @user3322836 you're welcome, don"t hesitate to vote up or accept so. But a question, you hardcoded `3` what about the array is 10 length or 20 length ?

Comment: azro i have another question , no need to print this i need to return as string means  string returnFunct(int [] arry] ){ ..../....//.. return "952"}

Comment: azro other question  thisnk I have int array {1,2,3,4,5}  need to divide it into list length 3 like {1,2,3}{2,3,4},{3,4} and sum of each

Answer (score 4):

Don’t use an external counter. Since streams do not guaranty a particular processing order, there is no guaranty that the counter updates truly reflect the actual element position.

A straight-forward solution isn’t that complicated:

```
int[] array = {4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1};
int chunks = 3, chunkSize = array.length/chunks;
IntStream.range(0, chunks).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i+" "
    +Arrays.stream(array, i*=chunkSize, i+chunkSize).sum()));
```

This will ignore excess elements, if the array length is not divisible by three.

If the array truly is `Integer[]` rather than `int[]`, you have to unbox the elements:

```
Integer[] array = {4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1};
int chunks = 3, chunkSize = array.length/chunks;
IntStream.range(0, chunks).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i+" "
    +Arrays.stream(array, i*=chunkSize, i+chunkSize)
           .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
           .sum()));
```

The above solutions are for “divide integer list to 3 parts”, matching your question’s title. If you want to split into parts of length three instead, you just have to change the solution to

```
int chunkSize = 3;
IntStream.range(0, array.length/chunkSize).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i+" "
    +Arrays.stream(array, i*=chunkSize, i+chunkSize)
           .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
           .sum()));
```

If you want to handle array length not divisible by `chunkSize` by processing the last, possibly shorter chunk, you can use

```
Integer[] array = {4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 100};
int chunkSize = 3;
IntStream.range(0, (array.length+chunkSize-1)/chunkSize)
    .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i+" "
        +Arrays.stream(array, i*=chunkSize, Math.min(i+chunkSize, array.length))
               .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
               .sum()));
```

Comment: that `Arrays.stream` with 3 args made my day in learning something new, thank you!